# c++ efficiently get substring of string with index

Tags: c++, c++11, substr

In my project i have to iterate over a large string starting from index=0 and get length k substring. I've implemented string::substr() and wonder if there are other efficient methods.

For example :

```
std::string S ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMN"
```

i need to get all substrings of length =5 starting from the beginning of S.Just like 
`"ABCDE"`, `"BCDEF"`, `"CDEFG"` and so on..

My implementation is like below:

```
    void geekfunc(std::string &str)
{
    unsigned int index=0;
    for (; index<=(str.size()-K);++index)
    {
        ++myseqmap[str.substr(index,K)];
    }
}
```

This function is being called ten million times and I welcome other methods to try.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve: do you want all the substrings of length `k` of your input string?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve with this function? Please take some time to read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and think about how it might relate to your question.

Comment: I ve edited the question for more clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using C++17, you can use [`string_view`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) as your parameter and map key type. This way you won't make copies of the string contents every time you call `substr`. Just make sure the string you pass to the function is not destroyed or modified while your map it still in use.

```
std::map<std::string_view, std::size_t> myseqmap;

void geekfunc(std::string_view str)
{
    unsigned int index=0;
    for (; index<=(str.size()-K);++index)
    {
        ++myseqmap[str.substr(index,K)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided you actually need to create copies of the substrings (which [string::substr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) does) I believe you cannot solve this issue with less than `Omega(m)` calls to the memory manager and `Omega(m * k)` copying steps total, where `m = n - k + 1`. This is because the standard requires each string to manage its own memory. Sharing (such as with the copy-on-write idiom) is not permitted, thus each substring will copy its contents from the original.

If a copy is not required and your compiler already supplies [std::string_view](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) you could try using that. Unlike `string`, a `string_view` only holds a pointer to a character and a size (which is exactly what you are creating your substrings from anyways). The required pointer can be acquired using [string::data](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data).

However, when using `string_view` you have to make sure the original string remains in scope for as long as the container holding the substrings and that it is not altered after the substrings have been created, as this may invalidate the pointers held by the `string_view`s. These can be adressed by wrapping everything in a class together like this:

```
struct substrings{
    const std::string original;
    container<string_view> substrings;
};
```

Where `container` is any container of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for [K-mers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-mer) for any given string.

```
static vector<string> find_kmers(string Text, int k)
{
    vector<string> kmers;
    int n = Text.length();;

    for (int i = 0; i < n-k+1; i++)
       kmers.push_back(Text.substr(i, k));               
    return kmers;
}
```